# Eclipse RCP build MacOSX: app folder empty

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-rcp

I have built an Eclipse RCP from scratch (based on Eclipse Mars 4.5.1), and I tried to export it to multiple platforms (win32.x86, win32.x86_64, linux.x86, linux.x86_64 and macosx.x86_64).

All the platforms work fine except macosx. If I explore the generated RCP folder, I found that the app folder is empty.

Do you know what could be happen?

Comment: You should get something called 'rcpname.app' for the OS X app.

Comment: Yes I have a "rcpname.app" folder. Inside I have a Contents folder, and inside a MacOS folder. But inside of this last folder, I only have one file "rcpname.ini".

Comment: Which of the several build methods are you using? Are you sure it is up to date as the format of the OS X app has changed substantially in Eclipse 4.5

Comment: I'm building the RCP from the Eclipse Product file. I followed the steps at these website (https://wiki.eclipse.org/Building#Multi-platform_build). What do you mean with your second question? I don't understand you. Thanks!

Comment: You did use `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5` rather than the 4.3 mentioned in the wiki?

Comment: Yes of course, I'm using Mars updatesite ;) All the other platforms are generated correctly

Answer (score 0):

It is like the build process in Eclipse (windows) when generating a macosx version, doesn't generate the folder structure correctly. There are some folders outside the xxx.app folder. If I put it into this folder, it works correctly.